# SETH-like hypothesis for machine with oracle access to some level of PH

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, oracles, polynomial-hierarchy

I am wondering if hypothesis such as Strong Exponential Time Hypothesis (SETH) have been studied for problems being in a higher level of the polynomial hierarchy when we give the machine access to an oracle.

More precisely, I am interested in hypothesis of the form:

$H_k$: For all $\varepsilon < 1$, QBF cannot be solved in time $2^{\varepsilon n}$ with a machine having oracle access to a problem of $\Sigma_k$, where the oracle can be called only on polynomial-size instances (calling an oracle on non-polynomial-size inputs looks way too powerful to be reasonable).

**Is there any evidence to support $H_k$ (or $\neg H_k$)? More precisely, is it known if such hypothesis is comparable to SETH somehow?**

I have not found any mention of this kind of hypothesis in the literature. The only hypothesis that I have found so-far are:

- #ETH introduced in [Exponential Time Complexity of the Permanent and the Tutte Polynomial](https://www.holgerdell.com/papers/Exponential%20Time%20Complexity%20of%20the%20Permanent%20and%20the%20Tutte%20Polynomial.pdf) by Holger Dell, Thore Husfeldt, Dániel Marx, Nina Taslaman, and Martin Wahlén but it is weaker than ETH.
- NSETH introduced in [Nondeterministic extensions of the Strong Exponential Time Hypothesis and consequences for non-reducibility](http://eccc.hpi-web.de/report/2015/148/) by Marco L. Carmosino, Jiawei Gao, Russell Impagliazzo, Ivan Mikhailin, Ramamohan Paturi, Stefan Schneider. But again, this hypothesis is stated for a problem "easier" than QBF.

I am also aware of [Beating Exhaustive Search for Quantified Boolean Formulas and Connections to Circuit Complexity](https://web.stanford.edu/~rrwill/QBFSAT_SODA15-cr.pdf) by Rahul Santhanam and Ryan Williams where it is proven that improvement on the complexity of QBF implies strong circuit lower bounds but their results cannot be applied directly to $H_k$.